# Model is null when form submitted

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, razor, submit, form-submit

When I hit submit, the `file` parameter is null.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  return View(new FileViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]    
[InitializeBlobHelper]
public ActionResult Create(FileViewModel file)
{
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
     //upload file
  }
  else
    return View(file);
}

public class FileViewModel
{
  internal const string UploadingUserNameKey = "UserName";
  internal const string FileNameKey = "FileName";

  internal const string Folder = "files";

  private readonly Guid guid = Guid.NewGuid();

  public string FileName
  {
    get
    {
      if (File == null)
        return null;
      var folder = Folder;
      return string.Format("{0}/{1}{2}", folder, guid, Path.GetExtension(File.FileName)).ToLowerInvariant();
    }
  }

  [RequiredValue]
  public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the cshtml:

```
@model MyProject.Controllers.Admin.FileViewModel

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
  Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_BackOfficeLayout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Files", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Create</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
      @Html.LabelFor(model => model.File)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
      @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.File, new { type = "file" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.File)
    </div>

    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Create" />
    </p>
  </fieldset>
}

<div>
  @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It's naming conflict and binder trying to bind your File property to FileViewModel object with file name, that's why you get null. POST names are case-insensitive.

Change:

```
public ActionResult Create(FileViewModel file)
```

To:

```
public ActionResult Create(FileViewModel model)
```

or to any other name

Comment: Shiat! I didn't believe it's gonna work but it did. Why indeed did this happen?

Comment: @Shimmy It's naming conflict and binder trying to bind your `File` property to `FileViewModel` object with `file` name, that's why you get `null`. POST names are case-insensitive.

Comment: i am getting sort of same error.but i dont get your solution

Comment: thanks, was stuck in hours could not figure why it stopped working suddenly

Comment: Thanks Man! Good Catch!

Comment: This is particularly insidious when you go back to modify older code written by someone else.  I never use "model" by itself as an object name and added a "Model" field to a nested object containing vehicle information, so code that worked for 7 years suddenly broke for no immediately obvious reason.

Comment: Thanks Man, it's work and so stupid, can't believe it!!

Comment: was stuck with a similar problem and this fixed it.. i find it ridiculous but hell, it works :D

Answer (score 3):

This solved my issue as well. It was a name that I was using that was similar to the model, which was similar to the variable I assigned the posted model too. once I sorted out the field name all worked as expected.

Of course the error was not helpful in pointing this out.