# ASP.Net MVC Model Binding What am I doing Wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I am getting a NullReference when I try to access the posted model.  What am I doing wrong?  I've tried everything I can think of, but I must be missing something simple?
Here is my relevant code:

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult EditQuestion(int id)
    {
        IFeedbackRepository rep = DAL.RepositoryFactory.GetFeedbackRepository();
        var q = rep.GetQuestion(id);
        SurveyQuestionEditModel question = new SurveyQuestionEditModel()
        {
            Id=q.Id,
            IsFreeText=q.FreeTextResponse,
            SurveyId=q.SurveyId,
            Question=q.Question,
            Category=q.Category
        };
        return View(question);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditQuestion(SurveyQuestionEditModel question)
    {
        IFeedbackRepository rep = DAL.RepositoryFactory.GetFeedbackRepository();
        rep.UpdateSurveyQuestion(question.Id, question.Question, question.IsFreeText, question.Category);
        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = question.SurveyId });
    }
```

**Relevant portion of ASPX:**

```
    <fieldset>            
            <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id) %>
            <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SurveyId) %>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.Question) %>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Question) %>
```

**Which creates:**

```
   <form action="/feedback/Survey/EditQuestion" method="post">

    <fieldset>
        <legend></legend>

            <input id="Id" name="Id" type="hidden" value="72" />
            <input id="SurveyId" name="SurveyId" type="hidden" value="4" />

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Question">Question</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="Question" name="Question" type="text" value="Test" />

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="Category">Question Category</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input id="Category" name="Category" type="text" value="Test" />

        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            <label for="IsFreeText">Does this question require a free text response?</label>
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            <input checked="checked" id="IsFreeText" name="IsFreeText" type="checkbox" value="true" /><input name="IsFreeText" type="hidden" value="false" />

        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

**Here is the model class:**

```
    public class SurveyQuestionEditModel
    {


        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Question")]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(4)]
        public string Question { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Does this question require a free text response?")]
        public bool IsFreeText { get; set; }

        public int SurveyId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Question Category")]
        [Required]
        public string Category { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: I might be wrong, but I am pretty sure your `Id` fields should be e.g. "*ModelType.PropertyName*" and not just "*PropertyName*", unless that's just when your rendering multiple types in one model.

Comment: Why would editorFor not output those?

Comment: Not sure, I noticed your using `<%:` syntax I take it your running MVC 2?

Comment: Is your SurveyQuestionEditModel class properties read only?

Comment: Does the view "Edit" exist ?

Comment: Yes an edit view exists.  Should I pull the question editing into another controller?

Comment: No, you can use the same controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like this question: [Model is null when form submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968452/model-is-null-when-form-submitted/13969007#13969007)

Replace your parameter name here:

```
public ActionResult EditQuestion(SurveyQuestionEditModel question)
```