# ASP.NET MVC Model Binding horror

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have two nearly identical scenarios regarding model binding on a controller action.  One works, and one doesn't.  I can't figure out why.

This works:

Given this ViewModel class:

```
Public Class SeasonCreateViewModel
    Public Property Season As Season
End Class
```

We have these actions

```
Function Create() As ActionResult
    Dim seasonVM As New SeasonCreateViewModel()
    Return View("Create", seasonVM)
End Function

<HttpPost()>
<ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
Function Create(seasonVM As SeasonCreateViewModel) As ActionResult
End Function
```

And everything binds perfectly.  `seasonVM.Season` contains the values posted from the form.

HOWEVER, this doesn't work:

Given this ViewModel class:

```
 Public Class UserCreateViewModel    
        Public UserPerson As UserPersonModel
 End Class
```

And these actions:

```
    Function Create() As ActionResult
        Dim userVM As New UserCreateViewModel()
        Return View("Create", userVM)
    End Function

    '
    ' POST: /Admin/User/Create

    <HttpPost()>
    <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
    Function Create(userVM As UserCreateViewModel) As ActionResult
    End Function
```

`userVM.UserPerson` does not bind to the form values the same way `seasonVM.Season` does.  In fact, it is `Nothing` (aka. `null`)

Does anyone have any ideas?

If you're curious about the views, they are structured identically, as in:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.UserPerson.NewUsername)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.UserPerson.NewUsername)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.UserPerson.NewUsername)
        </div>
<p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
End Using
```

AND

```
@Using Html.BeginForm()
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(True)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.Season.SeasonDescription)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(Function(model) model.Season.SeasonDescription)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.Season.SeasonDescription)
        </div>
<p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
End Using
```

Just a note: I've omitted irrelevant code, mostly just additional properties on the view pages.  I will say there is no property named "userVM" on my `UserPersonModel` as was the case here: [Model is null when form submitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968452/model-is-null-when-form-submitted/13969007#13969007)

**UPDATE**

OK.  I think I'm about ready to give up on figuring out why Season is binding properly, but UserPerson is not.

I thought I had figured out the answer, but it didn't seem to actually make a difference:

I have

```
Public Class SeasonCreateViewModel
    Public Property Season As Season
End Class
```

and I have

```
Public Class UserCreateViewModel    
    Public UserPerson As UserPersonModel
End Class
```

When lined up like this, the difference seems obvious.  In `SeasonCreateViewModel`, I have a property `Season` identically named to the class it is an instance of (`Season`).  In `UserCreateViewModel`, I have a property `UserPerson`, which is named slightly differently from its class `UserPersonModel`.  Because of this, I thought the model binder does not automatically match `userVM.UserPerson` to its corresponding class.

So I changed the class `UserPersonModel` to `UserPerson` so the Form values would match up in the same way they do for `Season` (ie, to the classname), but it STILL did not fix it.

**What does fix it**, however, is if I change this:

`Function Create(userVM As UserCreateViewModel) As ActionResult`

to this

`Function Create(userPerson As UserPerson) As ActionResult`

Why this suddenly binds properly, where it didn't before?  I have no idea.  Does this help anyone answer this question, though?

Comment: Have you tried to use fully qualified namespaces? Sometimes the problem lies within there.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that, Dillie-O?  I am using fully qualified namespaces, and are being referenced consistently between the Season and UserPerson code.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you are not creating a new instance of `UserPersonModel`. I could be very wrong though :)

```
Public Class UserCreateViewModel    
    Public UserPerson As UserPersonModel
End Class
```

I think in your action, you should do something like:

```
Function Create() As ActionResult
    Dim userVM As New UserCreateViewModel()

    //userVM.UserPerson = new UserPersonModel() -- in c#
    //userVM.UserPerson As New UserPersonModel() -- in VB?

    Return View("Create", userVM)
End Function
```

Or just ignore this answer :P

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this before and the answer is not at all obvious, but makes sense after you know. If you bind an entire model (rather than a static type), then every single member of that model must be posted in the form, otherwise, the modelbinder doesn't recognize the posted values as an instance of the model.

If you don't want to post every member, but rather just a subset, then you need to create a view model with just the fields you want to post, and use something like AutoMapper or just manually map the fields on the actual model in your POST action.

Comment: But I am posting every single member of the model, in both UserPerson and Season.  And it's working with Season but not UserPerson.  Or are you seeing something I'm not, maybe (hopefully)?

Comment: Are you sure? You didn't post the definition of `UserPerson`, and that's specifically what I'm talking about here - not the view model that wraps it currently, `UserPersonModel`. Is `NewUsername` really the only member of that class?

Comment: in my `SeasonCreateViewModel` there is a `Season` property.  When I post this, I do not provide values for all properties available in `Season`, yet it works perfectly well - it binds and everything.  However, I **am** supplying every property of `UserPerson` when I post the UserCreateViewModel, but it **isn't** binding properly.  It makes no sense.  Which makes me think it's something bizarre or trivial I'm missing, and not actually related to model binding somehow.